# SSIS package imports the data from the same xsl file n amount of times

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I created a `SSIS` package that is supposed to  import data from n amount of `xls` files.

I have 3 `xls` files in a source folder.
`SSIS` package supposed to run and pick only `.xls` files and import the data into database.

However, when run, it imports 3 times the data from the same file.

Looks like my for each container just runs three times and picks up only 1 file for import.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Because you have not specified the `ExcelFilePath` property to match whatever is mapped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string/21536893#21536893 http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48963/ssis-connection-string-expression-at-run-time-and-during-execution/48985#48985 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944217/ssis-connection-error-file-name-not-valid/8947212#8947212 etc

Comment: I did create `ExcelFilePath`, it is just hardcoded to a particular .xsl file. I need to make it dynamic. How do I do that. Btw, this is my first time working with packages